# AngularJs - Set ng-model from collection property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I'm having this rather strange issue setting the `ng-model` for a select drop-down list.

The property value I'm using for `ng-model` seems to match an entry in the `ng-options` but `ng-model` always ends up as `null`.

This is the method that gets the orders:

```
orderService.getMerchantOrders(qs)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.pagerService = new pagerService({
                    page: $scope.pagerService.page,
                    data: response.data.items,
                    total: response.data.total,
                    sortVars: response.data.sort,
                    pageSize: 5
                });
            },
            function (error) {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    $window.location.href = $scope.returnUrl;
                } else {
                    //show error message
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Here's what pagerService.data looks like:
[image]

The value of `order.orderShippingMethod[0].shippingMethod` is:

```
{"shippingMethodId":7,"carrierName":"Russian Post","carrierUrl":"http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/English.htm","orderShippingMethod":[]}
```

The select list values are:
[image]

Thanks for any ideas. I'm very much a beginner with *AngularJs* so I feel it's something very simple I'm missing here!

```
<select class="form-control" name="carrierList"

ng-model="order.orderShippingMethod[0].shippingMethod"

ng-options="shippingMethod.shippingMethodId as shippingMethod.carrierName 
for shippingMethod in shippingMethods" required>

<option value="">Select Carrier</option>

</select>
```

Comment: You should add some code that illustrates what you currently have surrounding the snippet you provided. You should show where $scope.order is defined, and where $scope.order.orderShippingMethod(s) are defined.

Comment: Great idea, updated with more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *track by* syntax for [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of *id* as *name*:

```
shippingMethod.carrierName for shippingMethod in shippingMethods track by shippingMethod.shippingMethodId
```

See it demonstrated below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.shippingMethods = [{
        "shippingMethodId": 7,
        "carrierName": "Russian Post",
        "carrierUrl": "http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/English.htm",
        "orderShippingMethod": []
      },
      {
        "shippingMethodId": 8,
        "carrierName": "Persian Post",
        "carrierUrl": "http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/English.htm",
        "orderShippingMethod": []
      }
    ];
    $scope.order = {
      orderShippingMethod: [{
        "shippingMethod": {
          "shippingMethodId": 8,
          "carrierName": "Persian Post",
          "carrierUrl": "http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/English.htm",
          "orderShippingMethod": []
        }
      }]
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" name="carrierList" ng-model="order.orderShippingMethod[0].shippingMethod" ng-options="shippingMethod.carrierName 
for shippingMethod in shippingMethods track by shippingMethod.shippingMethodId" required>

<option value="">Select Carrier</option>

</select> 
<div>
order.orderShippingMethod[0].shippingMethod: {{ order.orderShippingMethod[0].shippingMethod }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! I knew it was something very simple, thanks @Sam Onela!